# How can I print files sent via email on my remote server?

Tags: email, printing, server

I would like to know how can I print word files that are sent via email using my Ubuntu server. The network to which this server is connected has a few printing servers attached to it, and I want to use a specific print server to print my files.

Edit:
I've used lp and a script to convert doc files and it works, but I still can't figure out how to print email attachments that have a certain subject.

Edit 2: I've figured that out too, I've installed Google print on my server and now everything works except for color printing (I'm using generic drivers). Could somebody please tell me where can I download the PPD driver for my printer? It's an Olivetti D-color mf30.

Comment: I've used lp and a script to convert doc files and it works, but I still can't figure out how to print email attachments that have a certain subject.

Comment: I've figured that out too, I've installed Google print on my server and now everything works except for color printing (I'm using generic drivers).

Answer (score 0):

Is it a newer printer that directly supports print-by-email? (Newer HP and Epson printers do this, and other manufacturers might support it as well.)

I wrote a post here about it: http://forum.print-dev.com/discussion/9/printing-directly-from-rails-app-to-printer

Comment: No, the printer has a web interface but it can't print files sent using email.